# Using grunt-git for committing files to the repository

Tags: node.js, git, github, gruntjs

I want to push my app code to a already existing github repository using grunt. For doing the same, I am trying to use the grunt-git package but without any success.

My grunt config is as follows-

```
 gitcommit: {
        task: {
            options: {
                message: 'Testing',
                noVerify: true,
                noStatus: false,
                force: true
            }
        }
    }
```

Based on the documentation it seems to me that we don't have to specify the target repository if that is already added to the project!

While executing the grunt task, it keeps on throwing a warning as-

```
Use --force to continue.
```

Even using this command it doesn't work.

Can someone please share an example on how to use grunt-git package or even let me know what exactly am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why grunt for git unless it is part of some automated task. Give information about how you are running and all the error details.

Comment: `grunt-gh-pages` plugin may be a suitable alternative to the one you're trying if it's not working.  I use `grunt-gh-pages` to push a compiled version of my source code to the `gh-pages` branch on Github.  You can customize which branch it deploys to and the scope of files pushed